# How do I create a function that match regex with parentheses

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match usernames that I search with, with the usernames I get back from my database.

Usually the strings are like following: "Irene Milvoci (M)", "Andreas Kjapi (E)" and so on.

I'm trying to find a regex that will catch all my words, and also catch the "(E)".

The thing is, I just don't want to catch what's inside the parentheses, I want the parentheses as well.

From what I've tried, this regex will catch all the matches I want: `([A-Z]\w+)|(\([^]+\))`. But I seems to go crazy when I run it against my string: "Irene Milvoci (M)".

Have I written it wrong? I feel like it could be the "|" in the regex.

Let's say that I have a contact from the database "Martine Hover (M)". I would like the current output:

1. Martine
2. Hover
3. (M)

The final result for me, is that I want to make an html element that I return to my view, that will highlight the areas that match with my search term. So I will try to add `<em>{firstname}</em><em>{lastname}</em><em>{(M)}</em>`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find a match for `[A-Z]\w+` and then match an optional `space+(...)`? Try `[A-Z]\w+(?:\s*\([^()]+\))?` or `\b[A-Z]\w+(?:\s*\([^()]+\))?`

Comment: what is your output expectation ?

Comment: Please provide some feedback.

Comment: Let's say that i have a contact from the database, which username is "Martine Hover (M)"

I would like the current output: 


1.Martin
2.Hover
3.(M)

The final result for me, is that i wanna make a html element that i return to my view, that will highlight the areas that match with my search term. So i will try to add <em>{firstname}</em><em>{lastname}</em><em>{(M)}</em>.

Sorry for bad explanation, but i try to explain the best i can.

Comment: This sounds like a good time to fix your database design. You're violating [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF) and this is exactly the trouble you get for that: extra and inefficient code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
([A-Z]\w+)(?:\s+([A-Z]\w+)(?:\s+(\(\w\)))?)?
```

Applied to `Martine Hover (M)`

- group 1 contains `Martine`
- group 2 contains `Hover`
- group 3 contains `(M)`

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/8gO5H0/1)

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thanks alot!

Comment: Oh, i saw now that it didnt actually found any matches if there was less then 3 words. I wanna be able to match Martine Hover as 1.Martine 2.Hover, Even if the (M) isnt there. Same goes if i just write the firstname.

Comment: @AndreasWiggeWigertsson: Make the groups optional, see my edit.

Comment: Now it starting to look good! But there is still the problem When i write Martine H for example. Then there is no match at all. I wanna catch all kind of words, i just want the last "(M)" for example to be set in a group, which i couldn't before.

Comment: @AndreasWiggeWigertsson: Make non capture groups independant, like: `([A-Z]\w+)(?:\s+([A-Z]\w+))?(?:\s+(\(\w\)))?`

Comment: That will do it i think!, just need to add IgnoreCase to the mix!
Thanks for all the help!